# Magento migration 1.9.2.3 to 2.0.2 issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool, cli

I am trying to migrate magento 1.9.2.3 to 2.0.2. I have installed both magento 1.9.2.3 and 2.0.2.

Migration tool was not installed so i downloaded files from [git](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool) and used in my path `E:\wamp\www\migr20\vendor\magento`.

Now i trying to execute this code:

```
php migr20\bin\magento migrate:data -r E:\wamp\www\migr20\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\config.xml
```

And I get this error:

> [InvalidArgumentException] Command "migrate" is not defined.

What was the mistake here? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the files used for migration are missed when manually used the migration tool. 
I have solved by reinstalling magento2 and installing magento-migration-tool using `composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com` in command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine it's most likely some autoload files missing if you manually added the files. Try installing the migration tool [using composer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Magento2 says it is not recognizing the argument of the command line tool, try to do a DI compile.

```
rm -rf var/{di,generation}
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

It might happen that you have added a module, in this case the migration tool, and you need to (re)compile the code first in order for it to be available.